# What is the relationship between AEL, Class, and MPE for laser safety?

Tags: laser, laboratory-safety

I'm trying to establish safety limits for a laser system but can't resolve the information in the ANSI manual.

---

Here is my understanding so far:

[MPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety#Maximum_permissible_exposure) (Maximum Permissible Exposure) is based on health studies for specific irradiance values.  That's easy.

The units of AEL (Accessible Emission Limit) appears to be power.  The definition of AEL for a Class 1 laser specifically says (section 3.2.4.1) to multiply the MPE (based on the maximum required exposure for the unaided eye) with the aperture. This also results in units of power.

But nowhere is my calculation actually using the power of the source! It makes more sense to measure irradiance through the relevant aperture and compare it to some threshold (which is the same thing for determining how much protection is needed).

Comment: If for a real system, you really should find and talk to your institute’s Laser Safety Officer who knows how to interpret ANSI-Z and perform the calculations properly.

Comment: To add to @JonCuster's comment: none of these things is obvious: the specifications are thoroughly arcane even for trained optical physicists and you really need to see a laser safety officer who has been trained in how the read these specifications. I did this training a number of years ago for IEC/ISO60825 and there are a number of ambiguous points in the spec that need clarification by someone who knows how they're meant to be interpreted (in my case, the trainer was from the IEC/ISO60825 standard committee). It's a bit like studying case law in less advanced, common law legal systems.

Comment: I thank you kind sirs.  Maybe this will remove this monkey from my back!